# freebase mqlread query exception

Tags: java, netbeans, freebase

I'm using freebase query in order to get some info.

```
    JSON mqlJsonResult = freebase.mqlread(this.query,this.envelope,null);
    return mqlJsonResult;
```

Where:

- this.query = "{"return":"count","name~=":"*BARCELONA*","type":"/travel/travel_destination"}"
- this.envelope = "{}"

I've checked the query here: http://www.freebase.com/query and the result is 1.

But in my app I'm getting this exception:

```
com.freebase.api.FreebaseException: Unexpected character (<) at position 3.
```

I have no idea how to continue.

Thanks! :)

EDIT: I'm using netbeans IDE 7.1.2 and Tomcat as webserver and the following libraries:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

import com.freebase.api.Freebase;
import com.freebase.json.JSON;
import com.uem.gsi.tmt.util.Constants;

import static com.freebase.json.JSON.o;
import static com.freebase.json.JSON.a;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem: Freebase was sold to Google, so the functions for accesing the data have changed.

I will try to change the database.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide very much context (especially what client library you are using), but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're using a client library which is still trying to use the retired API endpoint and is getting caught by Google's wacky redirect to an HTML page instead of a returning an HTML status of Gone or a reasonable JSON error.

Comment: Thanks Tom, the quotes are correctly typped, i thinks is some error in mqlread function, but no idea at all.

Comment: OK, I've added a new guess.  Let me know when I've used up my 20 questions.